# SQL получение записей не входящих в две другие таблицы

Tags: sql, join

Есть три таблицы:

1)clients(id)

2)clients_services(id,client_id,service_id)

3)services(id)

Нужно получить id услуг не подключенных у клиента

Использую такой запрос

```sql
select services.id
from services_settings left join
(
  select clients_services.service_id 
  from clients inner join clients_services on clients_services.client_id = clients.id 
  where clients.id = 4
) as temp 
on service.id = temp.service_id
```

Он мне выдает все значения из таблицы services.хотя по лефту должен выдать то что не входит в таблицу temp(объединение clients и clients_services)
где я ошибаюсь?

Comment: `left` джойнит таблицу даже если нет соответствий (поля из приджойненной таблицы будут `null`). Т.к. вам не нужны те записи, где поля не `null`, то так и надо писать `WHERE temp.service_id IS NULL`

Comment: @BOPOH, спасибо=)

Comment: @BOPOH может стоит офрмить ответ как ответ, а не как комментарий?

Comment: @PashaPash, коммент написать - 1 минута, а ответ до сих пор пишу

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> > хотя по лефту должен выдать то что не входит в таблицу temp

Это утверждение ошибочно.

`LEFT JOIN` работает следующим образом: берется строка основной таблицы и по указанному условию ищется строка в приджойненной таблице:

- если такая строка найдена, то она добавляется к текущей строке результирующего набора;
- если таких строк было несколько, то строка исходной таблицы дублируется соответствующее число раз и к каждому дубликату добавляется очередная найденная строка;
- если же строку, удовлетворяющую заданному условию, найти не удалось, то исходной строке будет поставлена в соответствие "мнимая" строка со значениями всех полей равными `null` (т.е. пустая строка).

Таким образом, если при использовании `LEFT JOIN` необходимо отсеять "мнимые" (т.е. несуществующие) строки, то необходимо добавить проверку на `null`:

```
select services.id
from services_settings left join
(
    select clients_services.service_id 
    from clients

    inner join clients_services
    on clients_services.client_id = clients.id 

    where clients.id = 4
) as temp 
on service.id = temp.service_id

where temp.service_id is null
```

---

Замечание по вашему коду: если внимательно посмотреть на запрос, то увидим, что условие `where clients.id = 4` фактически равно `where clients_services.client_id = 4`. Поэтому от джойна таблицы клиентов можно избавиться, а значит можно избавиться и от внутреннего `select`'а:

```
select services.id
from services_settings

left join clients_services
on service.id = clients_services.service_id

where clients_services.service_id is null
    and clients_services.client_id = 4
```

Это должно ускорить выборку, но надо смотреть на план выполнения запроса. Возможно понадобится вносить изменения в индексы или сам запрос